# PHP Blank lines on foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have a method which queries top 5 items from selected table and adds each row to a list. When i try to make an ordered list from this method, it lists 10 items not 5. One correct line and one blank line on each iteration. I've tried both a method in class and a function outside of the class but result is same.

Here is my method:

```
/**
* @return array
*/
public function top_list(): array {
    /* @var mysqli_result $result */
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM users ORDER BY performance DESC LIMIT 5";
    $result = self::$database->query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        exit("Database query failed.");
    }
    $list = [];
    while ($record = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $list[] = $record;
    }
    $result->free();
    return $list;
}
```

and here is my ordered list:

```
$user = new User();
foreach ($user->top_list() as $item) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo $item["name"];
    echo "<li />";
}
```

[Result of ordered list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzmiI.png)

[print_r of $user->top_list()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtNxo.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo "<li />";`

should be

`echo "</li>";`

You are not closing the list tag correctly, and the HTML renderer is attempting to create a new list item for each `<li />` it sees.

Comment: Thanks for your well explained help and i can't believe myself.

Comment: You're welcome! No worries; it happens to the best of us. :-)